# Excel- Find value in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to find the corresponding value in the table?

The first one worked, but I tried to replicate it to the others and give the error.

[image]

Comment: I guess you are using `LOOKUP` function in the Netherlands. You need to use `$`-notation for the second input argument and to use the third optional input argument, for example: `LOOKUP(D2,$A1:$C$1, A2:C2)` then you can extend it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula in E2 (then dragged down to E3, E4 and E5) should give you what you want:

=INDEX(A2:C2,MATCH(D2,$A$1:$C$1,0))

That should give you this:

[image]

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Yes thanks. I used this formula based on your 
   =ÍNDICE(A2:C2;CORRESP(D2;$A$1:$C$1;0))